# Connect 2 Domain Controllers using VM VirtualBox on this same system

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to set up Virtual Enviroment using Windows server 2012 R2. What i did.

1. Installed 2 Virtual Boxes of Windows Server 2012 R2
2. Promoted one to Domain Controller, installed AD DS, DNS
3. I' ve assigned static IP address to Domain Controller where i configured on 2nd Point, on Second domain controller i IP address from this same pool, assigned static DNS address this same on 1st domain Controller, on both VMs gateways are the same.

I Want to assign 2nd domain controller to my domain created on 1st controller.

I turned off firewalls on two Domain Controllers also trying to turn off on my main system (doesn't work). VMs can't see each other on the network, they can't Ping Together. Im using on VM VirtualBox on Network settings of this two VM this same NAT Network (Allowed mode to listen VMs)

DC Adresses (root):

IP: 192.168.10.100

Mask: 255.255.255.0

Gateway: 192.168.10.1

DNS: 192.168.10.100

2nd DC Adresses:

IP: 192.168.10.101

Mask: 255.255.255.0

Gateway: 192.168.10.1

DNS: 192.168.10.100

Any suggestions what i did wrong or i mistake ?

Comment: Your IP addressing is correct on the two VMs. This is a problem with how the networking in virtualbox is configured. Unfortunately I don't know that software. Look for other questions on superuser dealing with this as I'm sure this has been asked here before.

Answer (score 0):

OK i figured out my problem. I forgot to change MAC Address on Card i was using this same MAC on 2 VMs. I changed 1 address and i run *sysprep* on 2nd machine (because i using cloning operation and SIDs on other machines can't be the same)

Problem Solved.